# Vue.js : Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of ty pe string. Received undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

### Version:

- Vue.js: 2.96
- npm:6.13.4
- node:12.16.0

### Details:

When I ran the command `npm run dev` .The bug was reported like this:

```
F:\SourceCode\vue_template\ebook-demo>npm run dev

> ebook-demo@1.0.0 dev F:\SourceCode\vue_template\ebook-demo
> webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js

 13% building modules 33/37 modules 4 active ...e\vue_template\ebook-demo\src\App.vue{ p
arser: "babylon" } is deprecated; we now treat it as { parser: "babel" }.
 94% asset optimization

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                         16:28:59


 error  in ./src/assets/style/global.scss

Module build failed: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of ty
pe string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:117:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at getSassOptions (F:\SourceCode\vue_template\ebook-demo\node_modules\sass-loader\di
st\utils.js:160:37)
    at Object.loader (F:\SourceCode\vue_template\ebook-demo\node_modules\sass-loader\dis
t\index.js:36:49)

 @ ./src/assets/style/global.scss 4:14-211 13:3-17:5 14:22-219
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://0.0.0.0:8081 webpack/hot/dev-server ./src/ma
in.js
```

when I uninstalled and install again the Vue.js...The same bug appeared again.

The Code at global.scss:

```
@import 'reset';
//1px=fontSize
$fontSize: 37.5;
@function px2rem($px) {
    @return ($px / $fontSize)+rem;
}

@mixin center() {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

#### The directory like below:

[image]

I've imported the reset.scss like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to import `reset.scss` using a relative path ?

Comment: I've tried, but it didn't work

Comment: There is something wrong in your configuration. Can you reproduce the issue on CodeSandbox ?